# How to show the next line after insert a command on linux terminal?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

Sometimes when you insert a command on the linux terminal the output it's too big, so yo have to scroll till the beginning. I want to know if there is a way to avoid that scrolling and going to the first line of the output after we insert the command.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `more` or `less` commands?
 Usage:

```
$ less a-big-plain-text-file.txt
$ ### same syntax for `more` (see respective man's)
```

Then you are positioned at the beginning of the file, you can scroll it or even search for the line number (type a number and press enter), etc,etc.

Play with `head` and `tail` too.

Answer (score 0):

pipe the output of your cmd to a file and then open the file to view its first line `ls -lrt > abcd.txt`

Comment: this one works, but I though there was a linux command that could accomplish that.